# How to compare SHA1 of 512KB data with the given SHA1 from meta info file?

Tags: c, buffer

My program sends a request for data with 512KB size to a server. In order to check data integrity, It has the given SHA1 from a meta-information file. I'm going to compare SHA1 of this received data with the given SHA1 like, but I think something goes wrong because the buffer size is too big.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char given_SHA1[20]; // assume that it has some value.
    char received_buffer[524288]; // Assume that this holds 512KB data from a socket. does not make sense. it is too big.
    char SHA1_received[20]; 

    SHA1(received_buffer, SHA1_received); // SHA1_received will get SHA1 of 512KB data.
    if(strcmp(SHA1_received, given_SHA1) == 0)
    {
        printf("received data is OK\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Is there any alternative way to do stuff that this code does, instead of declaring 512KB buffer as local variable?

Comment: Is the problem that you can't declare `char received_buffer[524288];`, or that the `SHA1()` function doesn't work with such a large buffer? Or don't you know?

Comment: char received_buffer[524288];  is not that big.

Comment: I can't declare `char recevied_buffer[524288]`. I think declaring a such big buffer does not make sense because multiple threads have to do this. Although I have never tried this, I think `SHA1` function might work with such a big buffer.

Comment: Yes the documentation suggests that `SHA1` can cope - so see the first part of my answer below for the most likely approach.

Comment: I'm a student, not field-developer. Because so far I have never declared such a big buffer, I think this buffer is too big. Does competent developer often declare such buffer?

Comment: It's absolutely fine - especially since you will remember to `free` it afterwards (right?). Presumably you are doing something with the message after testing its integrity, so having all in RAM is a good idea. It's only half a MB - don't sweat it. Of course it does depend on the application and the target (if you are starved for RAM you may need to re-think the approach; similarly, if your message comes in slowly and in smaller chunks, it might be worth processing a chunk at a time.) But don't sweat it!

Comment: Note that normally SHA1 functions don't return an hex hash, they return a binary hash. The length of the buffer you used (20) suggests you know this (because SHA1 is 160 bits -> 20 bytes, while the hex of a sha1 would be 40 characters). So if it's a binary hash, you have to use `memcmp` instead of `strcmp`!

Comment: Other problem: the last block won't be 524288, it will be smaller. You have to tell the SHA1 function the length of the buffer.

Comment: @xanatos Thank you for comments. I've forgot those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that your problem is simply one of allocating the buffer. In which case you could simply do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

char *received_buffer;
received_buffer = (char*) malloc(524288 * sizeof(char));
```

After you have finished using the buffer, remember to do

```
free(received_buffer);
```

So you don't hold on to memory you no longer use (and, in the case of looping over this code multiple times, you avoid a "memory leak").

As an alternative solution, you can follow the directions given at http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html for dealing with fragments of messages (repeated calls to process the entire message - i.e. working with smaller chunks):

> SHA1() computes the SHA-1 message digest of the n bytes at d and
>   places it in md (which must have space for SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH == 20
>   bytes of output). If md is NULL, the digest is placed in a static
>   array.
>
> The following functions may be used if the message is not completely
>   stored in memory:
>
> SHA1_Init() initializes a SHA_CTX structure.
>
> SHA1_Update() can be called repeatedly with chunks of the message to
>   be hashed (len bytes at data).
>
> SHA1_Final() places the message digest in md, which must have space
>   for SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH == 20 bytes of output, and erases the SHA_CTX.
>
> Applications should use the higher level functions EVP_DigestInit(3)
>   etc. instead of calling the hash functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would keep everything as it is, except that I'd declare the buffer `static`. This will make it a "global" variable, so it's not allocated on the stack. It makes no difference in this particular use-case, except it doesn't occupy as much stackspace.

```
static char received_buffer[524288];
```

However, this won't work if you have multiple threads running in the same single function. Then you will need to use some other technique, for example using `malloc` - this should preferably be done "once per thread", and the thread should then be used to process multiple sets of data, and the buffer passed from the main thread to the "fetch data and calculate SHA1" function.